# Delete two tables based on results of one join

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, sql-delete

I am trying to delete data from two tables at the same time using inner join. However when I tried to run my query, an error

> SQL command not properly ended

error came out.

A brief background of what I am trying to do and some info on the tables, table1 and table2. So both tables has a same field, for instance "ABC". I would like to delete data from both tables using inner join but under the where condition of a field (XYZ) under table where it equals to a value.

This is my sql statment:

```
DELETE table1, table2
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.ABC = table2.ABC
WHERE table1.XYZ = 'TESTIT';
```

Comment: That syntax is product specific. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi @jarlh, I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Does your table names really have spaces in them? If so, put the table names in quotes (DELETE "table 1" ...)

Comment: Hi @MNos, nope, my table doesnt have space in between them, I will edit the question to reduce confusion, thank you!

Comment: Please post the real table (or real query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a child and a parent row with one SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640340/delete-a-child-and-a-parent-row-with-one-sql-script)

Comment: `FROM table1 INNER JOIN table1` is meant to be `FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2`? And is the column `ABC` one of the table's primary (or unique) keys?

Comment: Check my answer to delete both tables

Comment: Documentation for `delete` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8005.htm). You will notice there is no `join` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete more than one table.

You must use two different `DELETE` statements.

For this you can create a temporary table to store IDs to delete, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE app (ABC varchar(100))

INSERT INTO app (ABC)
SELECT abc
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.ABC = table2.ABC
WHERE table1.XYZ = 'TESTIT';

DELETE 
FROM table1 
WHERE table1.ABC IN (SELECT ABC FROM app);

DELETE 
FROM table2 
WHERE table2.ABC IN (SELECT ABC FROM app);

DROP TABLE app;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Oracle` you cannot `delete` from 2 tables in a single statement like you are doing. The syntax is wrong. You can use as below:

```
DELETE table1   
where table1.ABC = (select table2.ABC 
                   from table2 
                   WHERE table2.ABC = table1.ABC
                   and table1.XYZ = 'TESTIT');
```

Comment: No `FROM` needed?

Comment: `FROM` is always optional in Oracle.

Comment: It is? Thanks for the info.

Comment: @jarlh But mind it ,,its only optinal in DELETE statement but not in select :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but how can I delete the second table? do I use changed the position of the tables in the query?

Comment: This is a correlated query. So change the table names and coditions are matched, then rows will be deleted, You need to try it.

Comment: @XING: No. When deleting from table1 first, you cannot look up these records in order to delete from table2 - they will be gone :-)

Comment: @thalassophile: You haven't answered the question, whether `ABC` is one of the tables' primary or unique key. Is `table2.ABC` unique? Is `table1.ABC` unique or maybe `table1.ABC` + `table1.XYZ`? The answer to these questions can make a big difference.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Didn't i say if the coditions are matched then records will be deleted and its common sense that if i deleted the records from the table then condition will never be matched. Isn't it?

Comment: @XING: Well, maybe I am misunderstanding. But you are showing how to delete from one of the tables. OP is asking how to delete from the other table also. You say: change the statement accordingly. But how? OP wants to delete from t1 where there is a match in t2 and from t2 where there is a match in t1. So if you delete from one table, you cannot delete from the other afterwards because the lookup data will be gone.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Frankly speaking question is not clear as in what OP wanted to do actually. I just showed an example since his actual query was not correct. Rest clarification you yourself asked.

Answer (score 0):

A PL/SQL solution might be something like this:

```
declare
    type abc_tt is table of table1.abc%type index by pls_integer;
    l_abc_collection abc_tt;
begin
    select distinct t1.abc bulk collect into l_abc_collection
    from   table1  t1
           join table2 t2 on t2.abc = t1.abc
    where t1.xyz = 'TESTIT';

    dbms_output.put_line('Stored ' || l_abc_collection.count || ' values for processing');

    forall i in 1..l_abc_collection.count
        delete table1 t
        where  t.xyz = 'TESTIT'
        and    t.abc = l_abc_collection(i);

    dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || sql%rowcount || ' rows from table1');

    forall i in 1..l_abc_collection.count
        delete table2 t
        where  t.xyz = 'TESTIT'
        and    t.abc = l_abc_collection(i);

    dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || sql%rowcount || ' rows from table2');
end;
```

Output:

```
Stored 1000 values for processing
Deleted 1000 rows from table1
Deleted 1000 rows from table1
```

Test setup:

```
create table table1 (abc, xyz) as
    select rownum, 'TESTIT' from dual connect by rownum <= 1000
    union all
    select rownum, 'OTHER' from dual connect by rownum <= 100;

create table table2 as select * from table1;
```

After deletion there are 100 rows in each table. I have assumed we only want to delete the ones where `xyz = 'TESTIT'` even when `abc` values are common to both tables.

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct table1.ABC into Temptable
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.ABC = table2.ABC
WHERE table1.XYZ = 'TESTIT'


delete table1 where ABC in (select ABC from Temptable)
delete table2 where ABC in (select ABC from Temptable)

drop table Temptable
```

Comment: The idea is OK but `select into` does something different in Oracle - you would need `insert ... select`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.