# how to get full tables and columns with relations or not in ORACLE

Tags: oracle

How can I do to (left)join user_tab_columns with user_cons_columns and user_constraints to get the result below:

Table,          Column,         SourceTable,   SourceColumn 
ORDER,           ORDER_ID,        null,           null
ORDER,           ORDER_DATE,      null,           null
ORDER,           ORDER_CLIENT,    CLIENT,         CLIENT_ID
 
CLIENT,          CLIENT_ID,       null,           null 
ORDER_DETAIL,    ORDER_ID,       ORDER,          ORDER_ID
ORDER_DETAIL,    PRODUCT_ID,      PRODUCT,        PRODUCT_ID
PRODUCT         PRODUCT_ID,      null,           null

So... I need all table and columns but once a column is a foreign key,
I need to know the table and the column (primary key) related.

Comment: Seems pretty close to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight edits to linked answer:

[List of foreign keys and the tables they reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference)
all_ to user sources.

Course you could just use all and then filter on owner.

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner, 
       c.r_owner, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
  FROM user_cons_columns a
  LEFT JOIN user_constraints c 
    ON a.owner = c.owner
   AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
  LEFT JOIN user_constraints c_pk 
    ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
   AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
 WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
 --AND a.table_name = :TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

check following query :
select a.table_name,c1.column_name,b.table_name,c2.column_name from USER_constraints  a,USER_constraints  b,user_cons_columns c1,user_cons_columns c2
 where  a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name and a.table_name = c1.table_name and b.table_name = c2.table_name   if you just need FK constraint use a.constraint_type ='R' in where clouse.