# How to find reference column of foreign in key in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out how to look up the name of the column referenced by a foreign key.

Here's an example to demonstrate, keep in mind that I'm trying to look this up dynamically for hundreds of tables.

- WIDGET

  - ID
  - COMPONENT_ID
  - ...
- PART

  - ID
  - NAME
  - ....

`WIDGET.COMPONENT_ID` is a foreign key for `PART.ID`

I have a query to find `PART` (table name) but I can't figure out how to find `PART.ID` from `WIDGET_COMPONENT_ID`.

EDIT:

I'm trying to find out the **referenced column name**.  I can find the table name but I can't figure out how to find the column name.

EDIT 2:

(sql from [List of foreign keys and the tables they reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference/1730054))
For example, I can get the constraint name via:

`SELECT c_pk.constraint_name, c_pk.table_name r_table_name
  FROM all_cons_columns a
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                           AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
 WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
   AND a.table_name = 'WIDGET'`

This gets me something like `COMPONENT_ID_FK` and `PART`.  How to go from `COMPONENT_ID_FK` to `PART.ID` though I'm not sure.

Comment: @Corion it's actually not.  The closest I found is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference/1730054  but it only gets you the table name and not the column being referenced

Comment: Oh, indeed, that is only half of the answer. A constraint can have multiple column names, so you will also need to look up the constraint via https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1042.htm#REFRN20045 . If you have an example of tables + constraints, I could provide a solution via SQLFiddle , so maybe post that?

Comment: @Corion updated with more info

Comment: @bob-jaris, That question is a dupe of the one I linked to and returns just the table name, NOT the name of the primary key column(s) from that table name.  That's what I'm asking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query helped me get the info I needed:

`SELECT *
FROM all_cons_columns
WHERE constraint_name IN (
    SELECT c_pk.constraint_name
      FROM all_cons_columns a
      JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                            AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
      JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                               AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
     WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
       AND a.column_name = 'COMPONENT_ID'
       AND a.table_name = 'WIDGET'
)`