# Oracle database schema

Tags: sql, oracle, schema

How to get an Oracle database schema? How to get all table names and columns in those tables and any foreign keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to get all table names**

There is a lot you are asking here but this will work for tables from schema:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
   AND OWNER = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
```

This will also work:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE';
```

but it will return a lot of sys and system owned table names you do not want to see I think... or do you ? Your question is not so clear...

In the column called `OBJECT_NAME` are the names of the tables:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE';
```

**and any foreign keys?**

I have found this great query here:
[List of foreign keys and the tables they reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference)

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner, 
       -- referenced pk
       c.r_owner, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
FROM all_cons_columns a
JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                       AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                          AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
AND a.table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
```

I believe you now know what is the deal and how to find other things you need. Do go to the link I have mentioned here and research other answers here also...

**Note**

If you by any chance are not getting any results from your query's first make sure you have entered your table/schema/.../object names in capital letters like this:

```
AND a.table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
AND OWNER = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
```

Or if you do not want to think about it you can TURN THEM ALL TO CAPITAL LETTER STRINGS WITH `UPPER`:

```
AND UPPER(OWNER) = UPPER('SCHEMA_NAME')
```

Comment: `WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'` ... looks to be a typo.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Thank you very much. And in two places :)

Comment: Hi @user12853430, you are welcome. Can you please mark the answer as correct ?