# Show relations between tables in SQL+(Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database, database-relations

What is the query to show relations between existing tables in SQL+ (Oracle)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of foreign keys and the tables they reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has an extensive data dictionary. Views with database information begin with the `DBA` (for administrators), `ALL`, and `USER` prefixes.

Relations of tables are defined by foreign keys.

The foreign key information is in the `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` view with type `R`.

```
select
*
from ALL_CONSTRAINTS t
where t.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
```