# getting the parent table and the column value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am interested in finding all the parent table that have a reference to the current table
this is the query i am using

```
select owner,constraint_name , constraint_type ,  table_name , 
from ALL_CONSTRAINTS

WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' AND OWNER = 'AAA' AND R_CONSTRAINT_NAME IN 

(SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM ALL_CONSTRAINT 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P' , 'U') AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
and owner = 'AAA'
);
```

this will give you the detail of the referencing (parent table) yet not the columns involved making the relation

I want a query that will generate the columns name as well

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference

Comment: I want to know the table that is referencing the my current table and the column value that is being used for the reference \

Comment: When you find the referencing table and column, you can get all the values from that column. From your question it is hard to guess that you need a value, not a columns.

Comment: I am interested in knowing the column values that make up the relation

Comment: I've already answered: get parent column name and get all the values from it via another select. Since you have ref constraint there's no value that is not present in reference table. Oracle does not store all the values of all relationships because it does not need this informations to be stored.