# DROP TABLE QUERY ORA -02449

Tags: oracle

```
DROP TABLE Errors
```

results in

> ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys

How to drop the table?

Answer (score 1):

Handle referential integrity first.

What will you do with data that references values in a table you'd want to drop?

- if you don't care, then drop foreign key constraint(s), then drop the `errors` table
- if you do care, then - obviously - you can't drop it

If you don't know how to find foreign keys, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference-in-oracle-db).

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE;
```

it drops your foreign key or any dependencies in other tables. Only use it if you know you don't need this relation. Once committed it won't rollback.

If you don't want to drop them you can disable them.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
DISABLE CONSTRAINT constraintname CASCADE;
```

You can find the names of constraints by:

```
SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type, search_condition
FROM user_constraints
WHERE table_name = 'tablename';
```

Comment: Be aware, DDL's like `ALTER TABLE` issue an implicit commit immediately after execution. So you cannot rollback anyway - unless you use FLASHBACK

Comment: I didn't knew that. Thank you. Also thank you for editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the table where the table you are dropping(Let's say `XYZ`) is referenced.

You can use the following query to find such tables and constraint name.

```
select * from user_constraints u
 where u.constraint_type = 'R'
   and u.constraint_name = (select p.constraint_name from user_constraints p
                             where p.table_name = 'XYZ' and p.constraint_type = 'P')
```