# How to set foreign key nullable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, foreign-keys, nullable

I have a class configuration something like the following(just a sample not actual meaning) -

```
public class payment
{
    @Id
    @Column("payment_id")
    private int paymentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="")
    private Fine fine;
    //getter setter and other stuff
}

public class Fine{
    @Id
    @Column("fine_id")
    private int fineId;

    @Column("amount")
    private int fineAmount;

    //other stuff
}
```

I am getting `org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists` error message. In accordance with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991084/7315895) it is because a foreign key cannot have `null` value but my db contains `null`. I cant change the db or project structure so is there any way so that i can issue `null` value to my foreign key 'legally' ie without creating an exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot make @ManyToOne relationship nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511899/cannot-make-manytoone-relationship-nullable)

Comment: No reason a FK can't be null. The joinColumn annotation has an attribute nullable=true, did you try that?

Comment: @NathanHughes using `nullable` doesnt help as the field still remains not-nullable

Comment: @MarkusMauksch lemme look into the solution if it works, thanks anyways

Comment: @monster looks like your solution should be in there. no use in having the answer on two different pages :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Column(nulable = true)`

Is used for creation of DDL scripts and does not bring the desired behavior.

You need to mark the `@ManyToOne` as optional.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
```