# Finding reference table from foreign key in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

OK so I'm new to SQL and not very familiar with Oracle SQLDev, but the tool that I'm making requires that I access an Oracle database and gather some information. I'm trying to figure what table a foreign key is pointing to.

This database has thousands of tables.

Example:

I got a table (TASKS) that contains the following columns [id, user, task_type, task_group]. The problem is that all of this values are ids which correspond to another table, and the table naming convention is not intuitive.

So how can I find out what table `task_type` is a pointing to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select acc.table_name REFERENCING_TABLE_NAME, acc.column_name REFERENCING_COLUMN_NAME
from all_constraints ac1,
all_constraints ac2,
all_cons_columns acc
where ac1.constraint_type = 'P'
and ac1.table_name = :table_name
and ac2.r_constraint_name = ac1.constraint_name
and ac2.constraint_name = acc.constraint_name;
```

that should work

Answer (score 1):

see my post here (2nd answer) as to how you can add this as an extension in sqldeveloper:

[How can I find which tables reference a given table in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer/8230251#8230251)

Answer (score -1):

```
select table_name, constraint_name, status, owner
from all_constraints
where r_owner = :r_owner
and constraint_type = 'R'
and r_constraint_name in
 (
   select constraint_name from all_constraints
   where constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
   and table_name = :r_table_name
   and owner = :r_owner
 )
order by table_name, constraint_name
```