# PHP MySQL query against changing database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic

I am developing a PHP web based data entry tool with MySQL as the database. However the database will undoubtedly change whilst the data entry is going on (there is a lot of it to be done so we have started it so that it runs in parallel to the other development).

I have constructed the SQL queries so that the php can automatically:

> 1. Determine what tables are in the database
> 2. List tables with a certain prefix so that only ones that data entry should use are listed

However, what I cant figure out (despite checking php, sql and mysql manuals and tutorials) is how to automatically pull tables that are connected by foreign key, so that data entry have a list of items to choose from for the given table. So in short, how do I - using php - determine:

> 1. Any foreign keys for the given table
> 2. The table name that the foreign key points to

WITHOUT hard-coding any table names into the SQL queries?

Comment: ManseUK, thanks for the changes you made. I can see that they make my post more readable and I will remember to put lists in comment blocks in future!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to list your Foreign Key references using the KEY_COLUMN_USAGE view:

```
SELECT CONCAT( table_name, '.',
 column_name, ' -> ',
 referenced_table_name, '.',
 referenced_column_name ) AS list_of_fks
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = (your schema name here)
 AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME is not null
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;
```

This query does assume that the constraints and all referenced and referencing tables are in the same schema.

For InnoDB tables, using the Comment field of `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is useful for extracting foreign key information for older versions of MySQL.

I am unaware of any other way than the above 2 methods.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thankyou for the very quick response. I will try it out now.