# See all tables referencing a primary key

Tags: database, oracle

If I have a table "Person", with a primary key 'ID', how can I see a list of tables with foreign keys that points to the "ID" column in the "Person" table?

Comment: Although this is indeed a duplication, I think it duplicates this [other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer), and not the one referenced by the message that Closed this answer on this current page here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ALL_CONSTRAINTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1047.htm#sthref1110) system view.

```
select table_name
  from all_constraints
 where r_owner = 'OWNER'
   and r_constraint_name = 'YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY'
```

R_OWNER is the owner of the primary key and R_CONSTRAINT_NAME is the name of the primary key.