# In Oracle SQL , how can I find which tables reference a specific column (i.e have it as foreign key )?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was studying tis question - [How can I find which tables reference a given table in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer) ,

And It showed some code to find which tables reference a specified table :

```
elect table_name, constraint_name, status, owner
from all_constraints
where r_owner = :r_owner
and constraint_type = 'R'
and r_constraint_name in
 (
   select constraint_name from all_constraints
   where constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
   and table_name = :r_table_name
   and owner = :r_owner
 )
order by table_name, constraint_name
```

So I'm trying to tailor the code to get the tables that refer to a specific column (here  , PREPARER_ID )  ; this is what I tried so far :

```
select column_name, constraint_name, status, owner
from all_constraints
where r_owner = :r_owner
and constraint_type = 'R'
and r_constraint_name in
 (
   select constraint_name from all_constraints
   where constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
   and column_name = :r_column_name
   and owner = :r_owner
 )
ORDER BY column_name, constraint_name
```

This gives me an error :

```
ORA-00904: "COLUMN_NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 103 Column: 8
```

Comment: Ok...and?  That didn't work?  What happened?

Answer (score 2):

To query based on the column you need to look at [the `all_cons_columns` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1045.htm), as well as `all_constraints`. This doesn't have to use a subquery but following your pattern:

```
select ac.table_name, acc.column_name, ac.constraint_name, ac.status, ac.owner
from all_constraints ac
join all_cons_columns acc
on acc.owner = ac.owner
and acc.constraint_name = ac.constraint_name
and acc.table_name = ac.table_name
where ac.r_owner = :r_owner
and ac.constraint_type = 'R'
and ac.r_constraint_name in
 (
   select ac2.constraint_name
   from all_constraints ac2
   join all_cons_columns acc2
   on acc2.owner = ac2.owner
   and acc2.constraint_name = ac2.constraint_name
   and acc2.table_name = ac2.table_name
   where ac2.constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
   and acc2.column_name = :r_column_name
   and ac2.owner = :r_owner
 )
ORDER BY ac.table_name, acc.column_name, acc.constraint_name;
```

With a sample set-up:

```
create table parent_table (preparer_id number primary key);
create table child_table (some_col number references parent_table(preparer_id));
```

And bind settings:

```
var r_column_name varchar2(30);
var r_owner varchar2(30);

begin
  :r_column_name := 'PREPARER_ID';
  :r_owner := user;
end;
/
```

That gets:

```
TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME          CONSTRAINT_NAME      STATUS   OWNER    
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------- ----------
CHILD_TABLE          SOME_COL             SYS_C00101337        ENABLED  MY_SCHEMA
```